# `xxxx' : looks like a function definition, but there is no parameter list; skipping apparent body

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I have the code below which is a **bowling game**. This code was working good in Eclipse but I Then moved this to **microsoft visual studio express 2012 for windows desktop**, it gives the following error.

**Error 1 error C2470: 'cone1' : looks like a function definition, but there is no parameter list; skipping apparent body   c:\users\rocckky\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp  26  1   ConsoleApplication1**

Note: - I am not pasting all errors, it gives the same error where  type cones are defined.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cstdlib"
#include "GL/glut.h"
#include "GL/glu.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

#include "vector"
using namespace std;
int refreshMillis = 30; // Refresh period in milliseconds
int windowWidth = 640; // Windowed mode's width
int windowHeight = 480; // Windowed mode's height
int windowPosX = 50; // Windowed mode's top-left corner x
int windowPosY = 50; // Windowed mode's top-left corner y
bool fullScreenMode = false; // Full-screen or windowed mode?
GLfloat ballSpeed = 0.150f; // Ball's speed in y directions
GLfloat speedLine;
GLfloat ballMaxSpeed = 0.550f, ballMinSpeed = 0.150f;
bool moveBallUp = false, moveBallDown = false, isCollision = false, resetCall =
        false, moveRight = false, moveLeft = false, ballInRight = false,  
         ballInMiddle = true, ballInLeft = false;
GLfloat vp_x = 2.0f, vp_y = 10.0f, vp_z = 25.0f, vt_x = 2.0f, vt_y = 20.0f,
        vt_z = 0.0f, vu_x = 0.0f, vu_y = 0.0f, vu_z = 1.0f;
//eyex, eyey, eyez, centerx, centery, centerz, upx, upy, upz
/* the cones in the center */
vector<GLfloat> cone1 { 0.0f, 0.0f, -21.0f, /*rotated*/60.0f, -1.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
vector<GLfloat> cone2 { 1.6f, 0.0f, -21.0f, /*rotated*/60.0f, -1.5f, 0.0, 0.0 };
vector<GLfloat> cone3 { -1.6f, 0.0f, -21.0f, /*rotated*/60.0f, -1.5f, 0.0, 0.0 };

/* the cones in the left */

vector<GLfloat> cone4 { -4.9f, 0.0f, -21.0f, /*rotated*/60.0f, -1.5f, 0.0, 0.0 };
vector<GLfloat> cone5 { -6.7f, 0.0f, -21.0f, /*rotated*/60.0f, -1.5f, 0.0, 0.0 };
vector<GLfloat> cone6 { -8.3f, 0.0f, -21.0f, /*rotated*/60.0f, -1.5f, 0.0, 0.0 };

/* the right cones */
vector<GLfloat> cone7 { 4.9f, 0.0f, -21.0f, /*rotated*/60.0f, -1.5f, 0.0, 0.0 };
vector<GLfloat> cone8 { 6.6f, 0.0f, -21.0f, /*rotated*/60.0f, -1.5f, 0.0, 0.0 };
vector<GLfloat> cone9 { 8.3f, 0.0f, -21.0f, /*rotated*/60.0f, -1.5f, 0.0, 0.0 };

vector<GLfloat> ball {/* X */0.0f, /* Y */0.0f, /* Z */-3.0f, /*sphere*/0.85f,
        50.0, 50.0 };
//

void resetGame() {

    resetCall = true;

    cone1 = {0.0f, 0.0f, -21.0f, /*rotated*/60.0f, -1.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f};;
    cone2= {1.6f, 0.0f, -21.0f, /*rotated*/60.0f, -1.5f, 0.0, 0.0};
    cone3= {-1.6f, 0.0f, -21.0f, /*rotated*/60.0f, -1.5f, 0.0, 0.0};

    /* the cones in the left */

    cone4 = {-4.9f,0.0f, -21.0f, /*rotated*/60.0f, -1.5f, 0.0, 0.0};
    cone5 = {-6.7f, 0.0f, -21.0f, /*rotated*/60.0f, -1.5f, 0.0, 0.0};
    cone6 = {-8.3f, 0.0f, -21.0f, /*rotated*/60.0f, -1.5f, 0.0, 0.0};

    /* the right cones */
    cone7= {4.9f, 0.0f, -21.0f, /*rotated*/60.0f, -1.5f, 0.0, 0.0};
    cone8 = {6.6f, 0.0f, -21.0f, /*rotated*/60.0f, -1.5f, 0.0, 0.0};
    cone9= {8.3f, 0.0f, -21.0f, /*rotated*/60.0f, -1.5f, 0.0, 0.0};

    ball = {/* X */0.0f, /* Y */0.0f, /* Z */-3.0f, /*sphere*/0.85f, 50.0,
        50.0};

}
float ar;
const GLfloat light_ambient[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat light_diffuse[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat light_specular[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat light_position[] = { 2.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f };

const GLfloat mat_ambient[] = { 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat mat_diffuse[] = { 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat mat_specular[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat high_shininess[] = { 100.0f };

/* Called back when the timer expired */
void Timer(int value) {
    if (moveBallUp) {
        //  ball[1] += ballSpeed;
        ball[2] -= ballSpeed;

        if (ballInRight)
            ball[0] += 0.08;

        if (ballInLeft)
            ball[0] -= 0.08;

    }

    if (moveRight) {

        if (ball[0] >= 4.0) {
            moveRight = false;
            ballInMiddle = false;
            ballInLeft = false;
            ballInRight = true;
        }
        ball[0] += 0.156;

        if (ball[0] >= -0.02 && ball[0] <= 0.02) {
            moveRight = false;
            ballInLeft = false;
            ballInRight = false;
            ballInMiddle = true;

        }
    }

    if (moveLeft) {

        if (ball[0] <= -4.0) {
            moveLeft = false;
            ballInRight = false;
            ballInMiddle = false;
            ballInLeft = true;

        }
        ball[0] -= 0.156;

        if (ball[0] >= -0.02 && ball[0] <= 0.02) {
            moveLeft = false;
            ballInLeft = true;
        }
    }

    /* If ball reaches to Z coordinates of the all cones */
    if (ball[2] <= cone1[2]) {

        /* Now check ball's x axis that which set of cones has it hit */

        /* check for the middle set of cones */
        if (ball[0] >= cone3[0] && ball[0] <= cone2[0]) {

            if (!isCollision /* isCollision  ! = true  */) {
                cone1[0] -= 0.5;
                cone1[4] -= 10.0;
                cone1[5] += 10.0;
                cone1[2] += -0.3;

                cone2[0] += 0.5;
                cone2[4] -= 10.0;
                cone2[5] -= 10.0;
                cone2[2] += -0.4;

                cone3[0] += 0.5;
                cone3[4] -= 10.0;
                cone3[5] -= 10.0;
                cone3[2] += -0.4;
            }

            isCollision = true;
            moveBallUp = false; //  stop moving the ball

        }

        /* check if ball is in the range of x axis of right set of cones  */

        if (ball[0] >= cone6[0] && ball[0] <= cone4[0]) {

            if (!isCollision /* isCollision  ! = true  */) {
                cone4[0] -= 0.5;
                cone4[4] -= 10.0;
                cone4[5] += 10.0;
                cone4[2] += -0.3;

                cone5[0] += 0.5;
                cone5[4] -= 10.0;
                cone5[5] -= 10.0;
                cone5[2] += -0.4;

                cone6[0] += 0.5;
                cone6[4] -= 10.0;
                cone6[5] -= 10.0;
                cone6[2] += -0.4;
            }

            isCollision = true;
            moveBallUp = false; //  stop moving the ball

        }

        if (ball[0] >= cone7[0] && ball[0] <= cone9[0]) {

            if (!isCollision /* isCollision  ! = true  */) {
                cone7[0] -= 0.5;
                cone7[4] -= 10.0;
                cone7[5] += 10.0;
                cone7[2] += -0.3;

                cone8[0] += 0.5;
                cone8[4] -= 10.0;
                cone8[5] -= 10.0;
                cone8[2] += -0.4;

                cone9[0] += 0.5;
                cone9[4] -= 10.0;
                cone9[5] -= 10.0;
                cone9[2] += -0.4;
            }

            isCollision = true;
            moveBallUp = false; //  stop moving the ball

        }

    }
    if (resetCall) {

        if (ball[2] >= -3.0f) {
            resetCall = false;
            isCollision = false;

        }

        else {

            if (ballInRight)
                ball[0] -= 0.08;
            if (ballInLeft)
                ball[0] += 0.08;
            ball[2] -= ballSpeed;

        }

    }

    glutPostRedisplay(); // Post a paint request to activate display()
    glutTimerFunc(refreshMillis, Timer, 0); // subsequent timer call at milliseconds
}
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    switch (key) {
    case 27: // ESC key
        exit(0);
        break;
    case 'r':
        resetGame();
        break;

    case 'i':
        vp_x += 0.5;
        break;

    case 'I':
        vp_x -= 0.5;
        break;

        /*GLfloat vp_x = 3.0f, vp_y = 10.0f, vp_z = 10.0f, vt_x = 0.0f, vt_y = 0.0f,
         vt_z = 0.0f, vu_x = 0.0f, vu_y = 0.0f, vu_z = -1.0f;*/
    case 'o':
        vp_y += 0.5;
        break;
    case 'O':
        vp_y -= 0.5;
        break;

    case 'p':
        vp_z += 0.5;
        break;
    case 'P':
        vp_z -= 0.5;
        break;
    case 'j':
        vt_x += 0.5;
        break;
    case 'J':
        vt_x -= 0.5;
        break;

    case 'k':
        vt_y += 0.5;
        break;
    case 'K':
        vt_y -= 0.5;
        break;
    case 'l':
        vt_z += 0.5;
        break;
    case 'L':
        vt_z -= 0.5;
        break;
    case 'b':
        vu_x += 0.5;
        break;
    case 'B':
        vu_x -= 0.5;
        break;
    case 'n':
        vu_y += 0.5;
        break;
    case 'N':
        vu_y -= 0.5;
        break;
    case 'm':
        vt_z += 0.5;
        break;
    case 'M':
        vu_z -= 0.5;
        break;

    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void specialKeys(int key, int x, int y) {
    switch (key) {
    case GLUT_KEY_F1: // F1: Toggle between full-screen and windowed mode
        fullScreenMode = !fullScreenMode; // Toggle state
        if (fullScreenMode) { // Full-screen mode
            windowPosX = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_X ); // Save parameters for restoring later
            windowPosY = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_Y );
            windowWidth = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
            windowHeight = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );
            glutFullScreen(); // Switch into full screen
        } else { // Windowed mode
            glutReshapeWindow(windowWidth, windowHeight); // Switch into windowed mode
            glutPositionWindow(windowPosX, windowPosX); // Position top-left corner
        }
        break;

    case GLUT_KEY_UP:
        if (!isCollision)
            moveBallUp = true;
        break;

    case GLUT_KEY_PAGE_UP:

        if (ballSpeed >= ballMaxSpeed)
            break;
        ballSpeed *= 1.1f;
        break;

    case GLUT_KEY_PAGE_DOWN:
        if (ballSpeed <= ballMinSpeed)
            break;
        ballSpeed *= 0.95f;
        break;

    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
        if (ball[0] >= 4.0)
            break;
        moveRight = true;
        break;

    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
        if (ball[0] <= -4.0)
            break;
        moveLeft = true;
        break;

    }

}

static void display(void) {

    int const width = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    int const height = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );
    const float ar = (float) width / (float) height;

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-ar, ar, -ar, ar, 1.0, 100.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(vp_x, vp_y, vp_z, vt_x, vt_y, vt_z, vu_x, vu_y, vu_z);

    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, light_ambient);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_diffuse);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, light_specular);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, mat_ambient);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, mat_diffuse);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, high_shininess);

    /*    Center    */
    glColor3d(1, 1, 0);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslated(cone1[0], cone1[1], cone1[2]);
    glRotated(cone1[3], cone1[4], cone1[5], cone1[6]);
    glutSolidCone(0.8, 2, 50, 50);
    glPopMatrix();

    glColor3d(1, 0, 1);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslated(cone2[0], cone2[1], cone2[2]);
    glRotated(cone2[3], cone2[4], cone2[5], cone2[6]);
    glutSolidCone(0.8, 2, 50, 50);
    glPopMatrix();

    glColor3d(0, 0, 1);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslated(cone3[0], cone3[1], cone3[2]);
    glRotated(cone3[3], cone3[4], cone3[5], cone3[6]);
    glutSolidCone(0.8, 2, 50, 50);
    glPopMatrix();
    /************************************************************/

    /* Left cones  */

    glColor3d(1, 1.5, 0.6);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslated(cone4[0], cone4[1], cone4[2]);
    glRotated(cone4[3], cone4[4], cone4[5], cone4[6]);
    glutSolidCone(0.8, 2, 50, 50);
    glPopMatrix();

    glColor3d(1, 1.5, 0.6);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslated(cone5[0], cone5[1], cone5[2]);
    glRotated(cone5[3], cone5[4], cone5[5], cone5[6]);
    glutSolidCone(0.8, 2, 50, 50);
    glPopMatrix();

    glColor3d(1, 1.5, 0.6);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslated(cone6[0], cone6[1], cone6[2]);
    glRotated(cone6[3], cone6[4], cone6[5], cone6[6]);
    glutSolidCone(0.8, 2, 50, 50);
    glPopMatrix();

    /*******************************************************/

    /*  Right cones  */

    glColor3d(1, 1.5, 0.6);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslated(cone7[0], cone7[1], cone7[2]);
    glRotated(cone7[3], cone7[4], cone7[5], cone7[6]);
    glutSolidCone(0.8, 2, 50, 50);
    glPopMatrix();

    glColor3d(1, 1.5, 0.6);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslated(cone8[0], cone8[1], cone8[2]);
    glRotated(cone8[3], cone8[4], cone8[5], cone8[6]);
    glutSolidCone(0.8, 2, 50, 50);
    glPopMatrix();

    glColor3d(1, 1.5, 0.6);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslated(cone9[0], cone9[1], cone9[2]);
    glRotated(cone9[3], cone9[4], cone9[5], cone9[6]);
    glutSolidCone(0.8, 2, 50, 50);
    glPopMatrix();

    /****************************/

    /* THE BALLING BALL  */
    glColor3d(1, 0, 0);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslated(ball[0], ball[1], ball[2]);
    glutSolidSphere(ball[3], ball[4], ball[5]);
    glPopMatrix();

    /*******  Floor  ********/
    //glPushMatrix();
    glColor3d(0.4, 1, 0.20);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(21.0, -1.0, -25.0);
    glVertex3f(-21.0, -1.0, -25.0);
    glVertex3f(-20.0, -1.0, -4.0);
    glVertex3f(20.0, -1.0, -4.0);
    glEnd();

    /**  wall at the back  **/
    glColor3d(0, 1, 1);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(21.0, 10.0, -25.0);
    glVertex3f(-21.0, 10.0, -25.0);
    glVertex3f(-21.0, -1.0, -25.0);
    glVertex3f(21.0, -1.0, -25.0);
    glEnd();

/*  // speed line
    glColor3d(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(7.0, 7.0, -24.9999);
    glVertex3f(7.5, 7.0, -24.9999);
    glVertex3f(6.0, -4.0, -4.9999);
    glVertex3f(6.0, -4.0, -4.9999);
    glEnd();

      Lines between three
    glColor3d(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glVertex3f(-7.5, 7.0, -24.9999);
    glVertex3f(-7.0, 7.0, -24.9999);

    glVertex3f(-2.0, -4.0, -4.9999);
    glVertex3f(-1.5, -4.0, -4.9999);

    glEnd();

    Speed line

    glLineWidth(8.0f);
    glColor3d(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);

     %age from the range of speed by the current speed
    speedLine = (100 / (ballMaxSpeed - ballMinSpeed)) * ballSpeed;
    speedLine = (3.0 / 100) * speedLine;
    glVertex3f(6.0, speedLine, -5.0);
    glVertex3f(6.0, 0.0, -4.999);
    glEnd();
    */
    //glPopMatrix();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

/* Program entry point */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(windowWidth, windowHeight); // Initial window width and height
    glutInitWindowPosition(windowPosX, windowPosY); // Initial window top-left corner (x, y)
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);

    glutCreateWindow("Balling Game 3d");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutTimerFunc(0, Timer, 0); // First timer call immediately

    glutSpecialFunc(specialKeys); // Register callback handler for special-key event
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard); // Register callback handler for special-key event
    glutMainLoop();

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: 2012 doesn't have list-initialization for standard containers.

Comment: @chris I did something like adding -std-c++11 in eclipse then there was no error, is this the same case here too?

Comment: There's nothing you can do about it in VS except use 2013.

Comment: @chris Which one should I download? Professional, Premium or Ultimate?
I am using Windows 8.

Comment: I have no clue which version works best for you.

Comment: @UmairAyub: Recommendations are off-topic on StackOverflow (they attract opinions, not answers)

Answer (score 8):

**Visual studio 2012 does not have list-initialization** yet for the standard containers.

Take a look [here](http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/07/vs2013_CPP_compliance) and [here](http://cpprocks.com/c11-compiler-support-shootout-visual-studio-gcc-clang-intel/) to see the features already supported by VS. (or [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/06/28/c-11-14-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-vs-2013.aspx) for VS2013).